# boost::intrusive_ptr changing pointer address

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, smart-pointers

I have a base class which provides `intrusive_ptr_add_ref` and `intrusive_ptr_release` for subclasses to use with `boost::intrusive_ptr`.

The code in question works 100% on MacOS X and Linux. On Windows (Visual Studio 2010, 64-bit RelWithDebInfo with optimizations disabled), it works for most classes, but then it breaks on one particular subclass (nothing weird or special about it). I have this sequence of events stopped in the debugger as I type this:

```
1. T * t = get_pointer_from_lua(); // Correct value returned: 0x..7a38
2. boost::intrusive_ptr p(t); // ... and passed in here
```

... and then in the ensuing `intrusive_ptr_add_ref`, the value of the pointer is `0x..7a40`. ALWAYS 8 bytes ahead. I'm looking at a stack trace right now - `0x..38` goes into `intrusive_ptr`'s constructor, but it hits the reference increment function as `0x..40.`

How can I figure out what's happening here? My third party libraries are all Release builds, so I can't trace into `intrusive_ptr` itself - but I can't imagine it's so blatantly broken.

I'm at the end of my rope here. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**: just after I posted this, the obvious alignment issue jumped out at me. Maybe `intrusive_ptr` requires 16-byte alignment on Windows? The pointer is not directly allocated, but returned by Lua's memory manager. Off to Google...

Comment: This might be a bug in the MSVC compiler related to stack alignment requirements.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235286.aspx

"The stack pointer must be aligned to 16 bytes, except for leaf functions, in any region of code that isn’t part of an epilog or prolog."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further investigation, I was actually able to duplicate this issue on MacOS X, by adding a field to the base class and making it non-zero-sized. From there, I tracked it down to an obscure situation involving multiple inheritance (elsewhere in the tree, no less!), where casting to the base class actually *can* change the value of a pointer!